# How to make a component editable only by a Admin in adobe cq5?

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

I want to put a rule on my adobe cq5 component so that it can be editable only by admin user not by anyone else ? how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that what you mean by editing is the ability to open up the dialog and change the properties.

These types of restrictions are usually handled by permissions

Depending on the exact use case, you **could** modify the permission for that component so that content authors don't have the ability see the dialog node beneath the component. That would still allow them to see it in the sidekick and drag and drop but not access the dialog.

A word of caution this type of explicit denies are difficult to maintain over a long period of time.

Comment: I thought that ACLs were maintained specifically against content trees rather than node resource types? Could you explain how you would apply an ACL to all instances of a component? Or do you mean going into CRXDE and individually changing the permissions on each node instance?

Comment: ACLs are maintained against the node structure. In this case we would apply the permission restriction against the dialog node for the component in '/apps'. When you attempt to access the dialog, sling inheritance will attempt to access the dialog and fail due to lack of permission.

Comment: Ah OK, nice solution. Though the would-be editor still have a context menu, with 'edit' listed and it would just fall when they tried to open the dialog?

Comment: That's correct. The context menu, and the option to edit is still displayed.